# ViewBag in Kendo Grid ClientTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use a ViewBag variable inside ClientTemplate but unable to do so

```
 @Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.MainGrid)
     .Name("MainGrid")
     .Columns(col =>
     {
       col.Bound(o => o.Record).ClientTemplate("<a target='_blank' href='" + ViewBag.URL + "/#= Record#'>#=Record#</a>").Width(150);
     }
```

Above code doesnt create a url link but a simple text. In developer console, it gives an error

```
 '' #<a target='_blank' href='http://something.com/docs/workspace/#= Record#'>#=Record#</a></td><td class="#= data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['DateCreated'] ? ' k-dirty-cell' : '' #"
```

However, if I hardcode value of the ViewBag variable, i.e.

```
 @Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.MainGrid)
 .Name("MyGrid")
 .Columns(col =>
 {
   col.Bound(o => o.Record).ClientTemplate("<a target='_blank' href='" + "http://something.com/docs/workspace" + "/#= Record#'>#=Record#</a>").Width(150);
 }
```

it render the correct url link

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Could you please give it a try again with the last "/" added in your viewbag.url. Also use @ before the Viewbag and probably add .tostring() on your value.

Comment: Like this "<a target='_blank' href='" + @ViewBag.URL.toString() + "#= Record#'>#=Record#</a>"

Comment: Thank you. Those were good ideas but didnt resolve the problem :(

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. What is the full error you are getting in the developer console?